# Failed to Codesign ... errSecInternalComponent

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, code-signing, macos-big-sur

I am using Visual Studio 2019 (Windows) and a mini mac M1 with bigsur. I am developing a xamarin forms application and it is working on Android (physical and simulator) and IOS Simulator.

Now I want to try it out on my physical IPhone and IPad but I am having this Failed to codesign . Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "apple Development(...)" : errSecInternalComponent.

In total I have 40 of these errors with different dll paths

I am using automatic provisioning, without custom entitlements.
I did some search and I found a lot of suggestions to lock / unlock Login keychain access, but in bigsur this is not an option.
Also rebooting Mac does not fix the problem.

I also tried to revoke certificates and wildcard development profile and create them again (automatic in VS) and still the same.

I guess this is something about the new Bigsur system and Visual Studio / xamarin are not yet prepared to it?

one example out of the 40:

```
Failed to codesign 'bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone13.1-14.4/ToBudget.Mobile.App.iOS.app/libAcr.UserDialogs.dll.dylib': Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: ANTONIO"
bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone13.1-14.4/ToBudget.Mobile.App.iOS.app/libAcr.UserDialogs.dll.dylib: errSecInternalComponent
```

If someone has a solution, I would be thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a **Free Apple Account** to develop,

you could [Use Xcode to create a signing identity and provisioning profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows#use-xcode-to-create-a-signing-identity-and-provisioning-profile),

then [Deploy your Xamarin.iOS app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows#deploy-your-xamarinios-app) with Select the **Signing Identity** and **Provisioning Profile** created by Xcode.

Comment: Thanks @junior-jiang-msft that worked for me.